# Why do I get "AttributeError: __fields_set__" when subclassing a Pydantic BaseModel?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have this project where my base class and my sub-classes implement `pydantic.BaseModel`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int 

@dataclass
class FavoriteCar(User):
    car_names: List[str] 

car = FavoriteCar(id=1, car_names=["Acura"])
print(f"{car.id} {car.car_names[0]}")
```

But this error appears:

```
    self.__fields_set__.add(name)
E   AttributeError: __fields_set__
```

Does someone mind explaining what is going on? The reason why I want to use pydantic is because I need a way to quickly convert Python objects to `dict` (or JSON) and back.

Comment: I updated the post with a better example. This is similar to the code that I have, in my src.

Comment: Looks like you can reproduce this without the subclass `FavoriteCar`, and `dataclass` and `BaseModel` conflict in some way.

Comment: I did not provide a full example earlier. I solved the issue thanks to everyones help. You cannot use the @dataclass decorator with pydantic, I am not 100% certain as to why, but it might be because pydantic does something special to the annotated data in the background.

Comment: Seems like I skipped over something very important: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to decide whether to inherit from `pydantic.BaseModel`, or whether to use the `@dataclass` decorator (either `from dataclasses`, or `from pydantic.dataclasses`).

Either is fine, but you cannot use both, according to the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) (bold face added by myself):

> **If you don't want to use pydantic's BaseModel** you can **instead** get the same data validation on standard dataclasses

Comment: THANK YOU! I had converted from a dataclass to a BaseModel and forgot the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

```
E   AttributeError: __fields_set__
```

The first part of your question is already answered by Peter T as [Document](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) says - "Keep in mind that pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass is a drop-in replacement for dataclasses.dataclass"

The second part is that you wanted to convert them as dict.

> The reason why I want to use pydantic is because I need a way to quickly convert Python objects to dict (or JSON) and back

To answer to that part of your question you can use `asdict` of dataclass itself [source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#id43)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Point:
     x: int
     y: int

@dataclass
class C:
     l: List[Point]

p = Point(10, 20)
assert asdict(p) == {'x': 10, 'y': 20}

c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
assert asdict(c) == {'l': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}
```

There is discussion about these module level helper function(`.asdict` & `.astuple`) that they arent PEP8 compliant (should be `as_dict()` and `as_tuple()`) however finally they decided to keep consistency with namedtuple._asdict() and attr.asdict(). [source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#asdict-and-astuple-function-names)